# Can I know which computer accessed/modified certain files stored on Server?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

In our computer lab in my school, all our individual computers are connected to a main server dedicated to be used for our lab. We mostly store our files on the server, so that in case we cannot use our individual computers for some reason, we can shift to some other computers and access the files from there.

Now, we are currently facing some difficulties due to this. Many a times, students from other classes are deleting our files just for fun. Many are changing the file names to slangs. Losing our files are a great problem to us, because these folders contain our programs in java which we have done throughout the year. At the end of each month, we have to show our work to the teacher, so losing our folders is posing a great problem to us.

We have spoken about this to our teacher. She says that it is not possible for her or the other teacher to constantly go around and see who is doing what, as the class is large. Scolding is not a solution, as ninth, tenth or twelfth grade students hardly listen to the teacher.

I want to know if there is any process by which one can detect which folder was accessed by which computer, and when it was accessed and modified. In our lab, each computer has a specific name. Are there any log files or such thing stored in the server by which one can see which folder was accessed or modified by which computer and at what time?

If such log files are available, then we can ask the Principal (who is very helpful and friendly) to see which computer has accessed our folders and modified them, and at what specific time. Then we can easily find out which class was having their classes in the lab at that time, and as all computers are named serially, one can find out from CCTV which student was sitting at that computer, and then take necessary steps against that student.

The main server on which we store files, is on MAC, as far as I know.

*N.B.: On our computers, we are no given administrator permission, and we work on a second user account. So, it is better if all methods suggested are applicable to non-admin users also. However, if there is an efficient method and it requires administrator privileges, I believe we may be given permission.*

Comment: An Administrator might be able to determine who deleted a file but only if that logging has been enabled.  This information cannot be accessed by a normal user account.

Comment: @Ramhound Say, logging is enabled. After that?

Comment: *"ninth, tenth or twelfth grade students hardly listen to the teacher"*  This really sounds like more of a personnel issue than a technical issue.  If your faculty can't stop students from misbehaving, almost any security measures they implement can eventually be overcome.  That being said, the lab network should utilize NTFS permissions that prevent users from modifying another person's files.

Comment: @WrichikBasu - Before I spin my wheels finding an answer are you even an Administrator on the network?  If you are not an Administrator then you cannot access the information nor enable the logging, and I am not prepare to do hours of research on the topic, if you the logging is not only enable but you are actually an Administrator.

Comment: I would suggest using google drive, then nobody can access anybody else's files unless they are permitted.  The students can give there teachers access with a few clicks.  Otherwise create standard user logins, and give each student a home directory, then only that student can see their files.  Obviously teachers would have greater access.

Comment: backup to USB aka thumb drives.

Comment: @cybernard if I could do that, I would have never wasted my time in writing the question.